Electron APP(.exe file ) Automation Test with Appium
I want to autotest my electron app and the app have already been built up so it's a .exe file. When I try to open the file using APPIUM+Webdriver, the file can be open but I can't find any windows handled. When I directly try to find the element on my app. It will show "can't find such element."
I've try some methods, and still can't get into the app. When I change the app into calculator, it can find the element.
This is my code:
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.windows import WindowsOptions
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class AppTest(unittest.TestCase):
    APPIUM_PORT = 4723
    APPIUM_HOST = '127.0.0.1'

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        caps = {
        'platformName': 'Windows',
        'app': r"path/to/the/app",
        'appWorkingDir': r"path/to/the/workingdir"
        }
        options = WindowsOptions().load_capabilities(caps)
        cls.driver = webdriver.Remote(f'http://{cls.APPIUM_HOST}:{cls.APPIUM_PORT}', options=options)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()

    def test_log_in(self):
        sleep(5) 
        try:
            element = None
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((AppiumBy.XPATH, '//button[@class="yourbtnName"]')))
            if element!=None:
                 print(element,':Element found!')
            element.click()
        except Exception as e:
                self.fail(f"Can't found: {e}")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()`

